# MYSql Top 10 and Others Total

Tags: mysql

I have this query that works fine but I need just the top 10 vendors.

Then I need all the remaining totaled in a "All Others" row.

How can I do this wihtout a seperate query with `LIMIT 10, 18446744073709551615`

```
SELECT VENDOR_fullname,SUM(POTENTIAL_RECOVERY)
FROM COMPLETE
GROUP BY VENDOR_fullname
ORDER BY SUM(POTENTIAL_RECOVERY) DESC;
```

Comment: Any query that accomplishes this would probably be less efficient, in resource and time, then just doing two queries.

Comment: I am trying a seperate query but cant seem to get the result im looking for, I get a blank row
SELECT VENDOR_FULLNAME, count(*), sum(PotentialRecovery)
FROM
 (SELECT VENDOR_fullname, COUNT(*),SUM(POTENTIAL_RECOVERY) as PotentialRecovery
FROM COMPLETE
GROUP BY VENDOR_fullname
ORDER BY SUM(POTENTIAL_RECOVERY) DESC) AS AllOthers
LIMIT 10,18446744073709551615

Comment: The best way to get quality answers is by telling us what you need, instead of guessing about how it needs to be done and putting limitations on your question. I recommend editing your question or no one is likely to answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, I agree with @DamienBlack's comment, however *if* it had to be done in one query a `UNION ALL` could do the trick:

```
(
  SELECT VENDOR_fullname as name, SUM(POTENTIAL_RECOVERY) as recovery
  FROM COMPLETE
  GROUP BY VENDOR_fullname
  ORDER BY SUM(POTENTIAL_RECOVERY) DESC
  LIMIT 10
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT 'All others' as name, SUM(subtotal) as recovery
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT SUM(POTENTIAL_RECOVERY)
    FROM COMPLETE
    GROUP BY VENDOR_fullname
    ORDER BY SUM(POTENTIAL_RECOVERY) DESC
    LIMIT 10, 18446744073709551615
  ) as subtotal;
)
```

Comment: I get this error[Err] 1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: @user3232261 Answer updated, it was lacking parenthesis around the two parts of the query

Answer (score 0):

You can use union :

```
SELECT VENDOR_fullname as anme,SUM(POTENTIAL_RECOVERY)
FROM COMPLETE
GROUP BY VENDOR_fullname
ORDER BY SUM(POTENTIAL_RECOVERY) DESC
LIMIT 10

UNION ALL

SELECT 'All Others' as name,SUM(POTENTIAL_RECOVERY)
FROM COMPLETE
ORDER BY SUM(POTENTIAL_RECOVERY) DESC
LIMIT 10, 18446744073709551615
```